# Regular Expression to get VARIABLE02 from "convert(nvarchar(10),convert(datetime,VARIABLE02 , 121), 103)"

Tags: regex

Any one can show me how to get **VARIABLE02** from the string below
***convert(nvarchar(10),convert(datetime,VARIABLE02 , 121), 103)***

***convert.*(.+,(.+),.+)***

The above regex is working with ***convert(datetime,VARIABLE02 , 121)***, but once in multiple instances, it would stuff up.

Thanks for advice

Bin

Comment: How about `datetime,([^,]+),`?

Comment: If `VARIABLE02` is always a combination of  uppercase letters and numbers  your could do `[A-Z]+[0-9]+`

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to assert what follows after the second comma is not `convert` and capture your value in the first capturing group using a negated character class `([^,]+)`:

[`convert\([^,]+,(?!convert)([^,]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/bJKbtY/1/)

**That would match**

- `convert` Match literally
- `\(` Match opening parenthesis
- `[^,]+,` Match not a comma one or more times using a negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), then match a comma
- `(?!convert)` - Negative lookahead which assert that what follows is not convert
- `([^,]+)` Capture in a group matching not a comma one or more times (This will contain your value)

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

[`(?<=,)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?= ?,)`](https://regex101.com/r/bJKbtY/2)

Answer (score 0):

Seems not possible by using regex itself.

The slide below give a good explanation:
[Can regular expressions be used to match nested patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns)
Can regular expressions be used to match nested patterns?

But thanks all.